# A doubt in the proof of Heller's localization theorem in algebraic K-theory

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-k-theory

Currently I am reading through Dr. Weibel's *The K Book*.

There I encountered this exact sequence in the localization theorem of Heller:

$$K_{0}(\mathcal{B}) \longrightarrow K_{0}(\mathcal{A}) \longrightarrow K_{0}(\mathcal{A/B}) \longrightarrow 0,$$

where $\mathcal{B}$ is a Serre-subcategory of $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{A/B}$ is nothing but the localization of the abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ by the set $S$ where $$S = \{f \in\mathrm{morph}(\mathcal{A})\mid\ker f\text{ and }\operatorname{coker}f \in \mathcal{B}\}$$

Regarding this I have two questions:

1) Why is this exact sequence not left exact?

My reasoning : $\mathcal{B} \longrightarrow K_0(\mathcal{A})$ I can define an additive function $f$ just by taking the inclusion $\textbf{B} \in \mathcal{B}$ goes to [$\textbf{B}$]. Then by the universal property of the additive function I have a induced map from $$ K_0(\mathcal{B}) \longrightarrow K_0(\mathcal{A})$$
Which takes $[\textbf{B}]$ to $[\textbf{B}]$. So shouldn't it be?

2) In their proof they have taken $\Gamma$ to be the cokernel of $K_{0}(\mathcal{B}) \longrightarrow K_{0}(\mathcal{A})$

The aim is to show that $\gamma$ : $\mathcal{A/B} \rightarrow \Gamma$ is an additive function by defining $\gamma$$\textbf{(loc(A)) = [A]}$ where $\textbf{loc}$ is the exact functor from  $$ K_{0}(\mathcal{A}) \longrightarrow K_{0}(\mathcal{A/B}).$$

To prove this we need to show for an arbitrary exact sequence in $\mathcal{A/B}$ $$0\rightarrow \textbf{loc\(A_0\)} \rightarrow \textbf{loc\(A_1\)} \rightarrow \textbf{loc\(A_2\)} \rightarrow 0$$
[$\textbf{A}_{1}$] = [$\textbf{A}_{0}$] $+$ [$\textbf{A}_{2}$] in $\Gamma$.

This is where I am stuck in the reasoning that they have given. I am attaching a photocopy of their proof of this part. I am confused especially in the part where they state that $\textbf{coker(g)} \in \mathcal{B}$ and $\textbf{loc(ker(g)} \cong \textbf{loc\(A_0\)}$

[image]

Sorry if the question is kinda long, but I am stuck here for a day, I am tahnkful for any help.

Comment: Well, for (1), it seems to me that $\mathcal{A}$ could have exact sequences which $\mathcal{B}$ does not, and so $K_{0}(\mathcal{A})$ may contain relations that $K_{0}(\mathcal{B})$ does not. In particular, it is possible that $[B]$ is a nonzero class in $K_{0}(\mathcal{B})$ but is a trivial class in $K_{0}(\mathcal{A})$.

Comment: Ah! okay, but the way I defined the additive function and the induced map there's no problem in defining right? Please do share any example if you want, I was trying with mod-R as $\mathcal{A}$  and mod_{S}R as $\mathcal{B}$ where mod_S(R) is all the S -torsion R modules

Comment: Sure, seems fine to me. I'm afraid I don't have any particular examples in mind.

Comment: For your question 1), take as you were doing, $R=k[x]$, and then you have an exact sequence, $K_0(B)\to K_0(R)\to K_0(R_x)\to 0$, where $B$ is the subcategory of all modules annihilated by a power of $x$. Then, all the terms are $\mathbb{Z}$, in particular, the map on the left is not injective, in fact zero.

Comment: The map from $K_0(B)\to K_0(R)$ is zero, even though both are $\mathbb{Z}$. The map takes a module  $M\in B$ to itself in $K_0(R)$, but $M$ has a resolution $0\to F\to F\to M$ where $F$ is a free module over $R$ and thus the class  of $M$ is zero in $K_0(R)$.

Comment: I got it, I am posting the full answer. thanks a lot

Comment: Later by using the same example I also found out that if we take $K_0(M(R[t])$ =$G_0(R[t])$ then by localization theorem I always have $$ G_0(R[t]/(t)) \rightarrow G_0(R[t]) \rightarrow G_0(R[t,1/t]) \rightarrow 0$$. Where the left side map is always "0" map. Because I always have an $R[t]$ module SES $$0\rightarrow M[t] \rightarrow^t  M[t]  \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0$$ Thus$ [M]$ is "0" in $G_0(R[t])$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q.1) Has a pretty good answer in the comments so I am posting the answer of my (Q.2) I think I figured it out, it suffices to show that in the following exact sequence if we can replace $loc(A_1)$ by $loc(A)$ and $j$ with $loc(g)$(defined later) we are done.

$$0\rightarrow loc(A_0) \rightarrow loc(A_1) \rightarrow^{j} loc(A_2) \rightarrow 0$$

Let it be the exact sequence in $\mathcal{A/B}$

Then $loc(A_1) \rightarrow^{j} loc(A_2)$ has a representation $$ A_1{\leftarrow ^{f}} A \rightarrow^g A_2$$
Where $f$ is a $\mathcal{B}$ iso.

But that implies that $loc(A) \cong loc(A_1)$

We have another exact sequence like this $$ 0\rightarrow ker(g) \rightarrow A \rightarrow A_2\rightarrow coker(g) \rightarrow 0 $$

Since $loc$ is an exact functor from $\mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal {A/B}$  applying it on the above exact sequence we see that since $loc(A) \cong loc(A_1)$,

I have $loc(g)$ equivalent with the composition map $ j\circ \phi$ Where $\phi$ is the isomorphism from $loc(A)$ to $loc(A_1)$.

Proof : $\phi$ is represented by $$ A{\leftarrow ^{id}} A \rightarrow^f A_1$$

And we already know the the representation of $j$. So by the way they have defined the composition in the book we get $j \circ \phi$ as 
$$ A\leftarrow^{id} A\leftarrow^{id} A \rightarrow^{id} A \rightarrow ^g A_2$$

Which is nothing but $A\leftarrow^{id} A \rightarrow ^g A_2$ the map $loc(g)$